# How to convert fetching from @redux/toolkit/query/react to swr and cast result with the interface array typescrit

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, swr, next.js13

I wanted to convert code from @reduxjs/toolkit to swr but it will not work properly.

Here is a code using @reduxjs/toolkit

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';    
interface Blog {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    blog:string;
    image: {
        url: string;
    };
}
= export const myApi = createApi({
   reducerPath: 'api',
   baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost/blogs', prepareHeaders(headers) {
        headers.set('x-api-key', 'mykeyfdafdaffdafdafdas');
      return headers;
     },
}),
endpoints(builder) {
return {
  fetchBlogs: builder.query({
    query(limit = 10) {
      return `/blogs?limit=${limit}`;
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});

export const { useFetchBreedsQuery } = myApi;
```

The one using to swr is like this:

```
const fetcher = (url:string) => fetch(url,{
    mode: 'cors',
    headers:{
        'x-api-key': 'mykeyfdafdaffdafdafdas',            
        'User-Agent': 'My-App',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }
}).then((res) =>{ 
    console.log(res.body);
    res.json()}).catch(error=> console.log('error while fetching:', error));


const { data =[]  } = useSwr<Blog>(`http://localhost/blog`, fetcher);
```

The code i made with swr is not working and data will not be casted.
Could any one help on this?